# LazyLoad with ASP.NET Core - Relative Root Path?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-lazyload

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

> Using LazyLoad's `data-original` attribute while keeping ASP.NET's `~/` path identifier for my relative-root path!

**What the problem is:**

> `data-original` attribute does not convert my `~/` into the relative-root path for my images

**A normal image path:**

```
<img src="www/folder/file.png" />
```

**ASP.NET Core path:**
*This requires a* `~/` *to tell ASP.NET that it is going from the root relative path*

```
<img src="~/folder/file.png" />
```

**LazyLoad's image**

```
<img data-original="/folder/file.png" />
```

Does anyone have any experience getting the relative-root path to work properly with LazyLoad's `data-original` attribute?

**I've already tried doing this:**

```
<img data-original="~/folder/file.png" />
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer on my own. I decided on making my own relative root path variable within a Controller then returning the value into the View. All I had to at that point was to insert the variable using Razor Markup and its done!

**My Environment:**

- .NET Core 1.1
- ASP.NET Core

---

**Controller:**

`IHostingEnvironment` service has two properties of particular interest: `ContentRootPath` and `WebRootPath`. For my purposes, I'll be using `ContentRootPath` because I want to access the relative root path or in other words `wwwroot`

```
private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
{
    _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
}
```

Make sure to add the namespace to the file!

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
```

After I've finished laying out the ground work within my desired Controller, in the same file I only wanted a specific page to utilize my work. It will be represented in the example code as `Index` for the sake of simplicity.

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.wwwRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath;
    return View();
}
```

---

**View:**

It seems like Microsoft's .NET Core on runtime *or* build only converts `~/` into the relative root directory if it is within a `src` attribute within an element. So those who are using 3rd party libraries or are in situations where you need to specify a non `src` way of calling your files, this solution will suffice until they add extendability.

I'll be using the example in the **Question** as an example for the solution. So this code didn't work within the application as already stated.

```
<img data-original="~/folder/file.png" />
```

The solution:

```
<img data-original="@ViewBag.wwwRootPath/folder/file.png" />
```

**Note:** This also works great for JavaScript and CSS! Just place the `ViewBag.wwwRootPath` in your desired documents for consistency!